# Mockito casting to generics

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, casting, mockito

A part of a method to be unit tested is as follows

```
SomeTypeCollection<SomeType> someTypeCollection = ...
T currentObject = null;
while( ( currentObject = (T) someTypeCollection.next() ) != null ) {...}
```

The relevant part of the unit test would be

```
@Mock
SomeTypeCollection<SomeType> someTypeCollectionMock;

@Mock
SomeType someTypeMock;

when(someTypeCollectionMock.next()).thenReturn(someTypeMock);
```

However, although the mocked next() call seems to succesfully return the mocked object, the casting fails with the following error

*> SomeType$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGILIB$$98474372 cannot be cast to (ActualTypeOfCurrentObject)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be overcome in Mockito using the following changes (assuming

```
T extends SomeOtherType
```

is given in the method under test)

```
@Mock(extraInterfaces=SomeType.class)
SomeOtherType someTypeMock;

stub(someTypeCollectionMock.next()).toReturn((SomeType) someTypeMock).toReturn(null);
```

Comment: Sweet! Didn't know about the `extraInterfaces`. Very nice. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an explicit relationship between `T` and `SomeType`. Therefore, how could `SomeType` be cast to `T`? For this to work `T` MUST be a super class of `SomeType`. This is not a `Mockito` issue, just straight Java.

According to the test I would have expected your method to look like this:

```
SomeTypeCollection<SomeType> someTypeCollection = ...
SomeType currentObject = null;
while( ( currentObject = (SomeType) someTypeCollection.next() ) != null ) {...}
```

or

```
public <T super SomeType> void method(){
   SomeTypeCollection<SomeType> someTypeCollection = ...
   TcurrentObject = null;
   while( ( currentObject = (T) someTypeCollection.next() ) != null ) {...}
}
```

Comment: Regarding the method under test, T extends SomeOtherType is given, and we do not have the possibility to change that. However the issue could be solved in Mockito as described in the above update

Comment: what update? This is from 8 days ago, do you expect me to remember the exact previous wording to know what is different now? Since there is a casting error please show the block of code that defines the relationship between `T` and `SomeType` as this is the root of the issue.

Comment: In order: 1. "update" refers to the answer I gave myself starting with "The issue can be overcome in Mockito using the following changes..." 2. No, I do not 3. There is no relationship. The method under test header contains "T extends SomeOtherType" with no relation between SomeType and SomeOtherType, and since all this is coming from sort of a legacy framework, we do not have the possibility to change that. From Java point you are correct; however the question was, whether it can be handled in Mockito some way. It can. None the less your answer is appreciated.